# Workflow internal Status "suspended" with sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I created a workflow to automatically calculate the total cost (quantity multiply by price)
successfully to a list. But when i created items in list, I received a message from internal status `Suspended` with the information below:

> RequestorId: 47b96549-fd88-f950-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"error_description":"The server was unable to process the request due
>   to an internal error. For more information about the error, either
>   turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
>   {"x-ms-diagnostics":["3001000;reason=\"There has been an error
>   authenticating the
>   request.\";category=\"invalid_client\""],"SPRequestGuid":["47b96549-fd88-f950-9e21-97b20a957684"],"request-id":["47b96549-fd88-f950-9e21-97b20a957684"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"SPRequestDuration":["1920"],"SPIisLatency":["0"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer
>   realm=\"2b35e494-23a7-4eff-944a-9a740eaa7bb1\",client_id=\"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\",trusted_issuers=\"00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@2b35e494-23a7-4eff-944a-9a740eaa7bb1\"","NTLM"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Mon, 28 Jul 2014 07:02:04 GMT"]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

So the workflow cannot be consumed. Please help me to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to deactivate and activate again "Workflows can use app permissions" feature from site features.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before when using a workflow, for me the problem was a column for mobile phone number. I'd put a gap in the phone number (E.g 07712 345678) and when I entered the number with no spaces it worked. I'm no SharePoint expert by any means but maybe just check some of the syntax that's been used?

Comment: But here I just fill quantity. Exp: i have two lists, one is "Store Items" (name and price columns), one is "Store Orders" that will get item name from "Store Items", and the workflows will calculate automatically when item is created.